# Is there a CONNECT BY PRIOR equivalent in XQuery?

Tags: xquery, basex, connect-by

I'm using BaseX, which supports XQuery 3.0.

Let's say I have an dataset like this, ordered on the value of `<start>`:

```
<element>
 <start>1</start>
 <end>2</end>
</element>
<element>
 <start>2</start>
 <end>4</end>
</element>
<element>
 <start>5</start>
 <end>6</end>
</element>
```

I want to connect these elements by their end and start values, and group connecting elements together:

```
<block>
  <start>1</start>
  <end>4</end>
</block>
<block>
  <start>5</start>
  <end>6</end>
</block>
```

In Oracle, we could do something like this with `CONNECT BY PRIOR`. How can we do this in XQuery?

Comment: Did you already have a look at the XQuery 3.0 [Window Clause](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_3.0#window)?

Comment: @ChristianGrün, no I did not. Thanks for the tip, I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this behavior using a tumbling window, which lets you group based on conditions over element spans. Sliding and tumbling windows require XQuery 3.0, which is supported by BaseX.

```
let $items := (
  <element>
    <start>1</start>
    <end>2</end>
  </element>,
  <element>
    <start>2</start>
    <end>4</end>
  </element>,
  <element>
   <start>5</start>
   <end>6</end>
  </element>
)
for tumbling window $window in $items
  start $start when fn:true()
  only end $end next $next when not(
  $end/end eq $next/start
)
return <block>{
  $start/start,
  $end/end
}</block>
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks again.

Comment: Just a little addition… This works as well: `start $start when fn:true() end $end when $start/end eq $end/start`